# how to hook specific app on android?

Tags: android, hook, xposed-framework

I am trying you build an android app that works on xposed framework.
I want to be able to hook an app that installed on the device and when the app is launched to get event.

How can I do it?

Comment: Have a look at this link: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2709324

Comment: https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

sharePkgParam.packageName from handleLoadPackage method is to get package name from the resource that now is wanted smth from OS, than like in Xposed tutorial check needed method by FindAndHook or hookMethod